# Convert from List<double[]> to double[,]

Tags: c#, arrays

Is there an one-liner (no looping) that converts `List<double[]>` to `double[,]`?

Comment: That all depends how long you want your line to be  :)  (I suspect a few more than 80 chars).

Comment: @leppie, of course I want it as short as possible!

Comment: @leppie: Wondering if 80 chars length was some standard?

Comment: @abatishchev: In the old days, it was, nowadays, I think people prefer 120.

Comment: @leppie: Never understood such small sizes. 19" monitors has wide spread occurrence. Many developers has monitors much larger that 19 - and 21", and 25". So 140-240 chars is easy to look over, imo

Comment: @abatishchev: In the old days text terminals were limited to 80 x 25 - 50 (vertical lines).

Comment: @leppie: Old days - 80x-early 90x - no problem to understand, technical limitation, etc. That's that. But follow such standards in 00x - is a nonsense imo. Specially when it turns into `throw new Exception( + <linebreak> + "some long " + <linebreak> + "text");`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Converting to `double[,]` can only be done by looping through the list and requires  that all arrays contained in the list are of same size:

```
double[,] arr = new double[list.Count, list[0].Length];
for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < list[0].Length; j++)
    {
        arr[i, j] = list[i][j];
    }
}
```

Of course, you can easily create a jagged `double[][]` array of arrays by calling `.ToArray()`:

```
double[] array = new double[] { 1.0, 2.0, 3.0 };
double[] array1 = new double[] { 4.0, 5.0, 6.0 };

List<double[]> list = new List<double[]>();
list.Add(array);
list.Add(array1);

double[][] jaggedArray = list.ToArray();
```

Comment: You also can add trailing zeroes if array isn't of the required size

Comment: @abatishchev: Yes, good point. This would require an additional pass to find the maximum length entry in the list first so you can determine the array size needed.

Comment: Finding the longest array in the list first is better to use list[0].

Comment: @Danny: It's rather better to iterate one time more I think than trim all arrays longer than first

Comment: @Danny: `new List<double[]>().Max(a => a.Lenght)`

Answer (score 3):

Well, you probably can't implement it without loops, but you can make the *usage* a one-liner :

```
double[,] array = list.To2DArray();
```

`To2DArray` is an extension method implemented as follows:

```
public static class ExtensionMethods
{
    public static T[,] To2DArray<T>(this IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> source)
    {
        var jaggedArray = source.Select(r => r.ToArray()).ToArray();
        int rows = jaggedArray.GetLength(0);
        int columns = jaggedArray.Max(r => r.Length);
        var array = new T[rows, columns];
        for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < jaggedArray[i].Length; j++)
            {
                array[i, j] = jaggedArray[i][j];
            }
        }
        return array;
    }
}
```

Note that it will only work in C# 4, since earlier versions don't support covariance. This variant should work in C# 3 but it is more specific:

```
public static T[,] To2DArray<T>(this IEnumerable<T[]> source)
{
    var jaggedArray = source.ToArray();
    // same code from here
}
```

Comment: You could use `int rows = source.Count(); int columns = source.Max(r => r.Count());` directly without creating a jagged array first.

Comment: Yes, but I need the jagged array afterwards to access the data (I could use the ElementAt method but it's wouldn't work for enumerables that can be enumerated only once)

Answer (score 0):

If a 2 dim array is to be created from List of 1 dim array then looping is required, though it may not look like that at the call-site.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static T[,] ToMultidimensional<T>(this T[][] arr, int maxSize)
{
    T[,] md = (T[,])Array.CreateInstance(typeof(double), arr.Length, maxSize);

    for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++)
    for (int j = 0; j < arr[i].Length; j++)
        md[i, j] = arr[i][j];

    return md;
}

var arr = new List<double[]>
{
    new double[] { 1, 2, 3 },
    new double[] { 4, 5 }
}
.ToArray();

var j = arr.ToMultidimensional(arr.Max(a => a.Length));
```

Answer (score 0):

This syntax should work:
return new List{new double[] { minX, minY }, new double[] { maxX, maxY }};