# Cannot convert from double[][] to double[*,*]

Tags: c#, arrays

I have a code that looks like (more or less) :

```
public void INeedHolidaysNow(double[,]){
     //... Code to take a break from coding and fly to Hawaii
}

double[][] WageLossPerVacationDay = new  double[10][5];

INeedHolidays(WageLossPerVacationDay); // >>throws the Exception in the Title
```

I found the solution on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3546020/convert-from-listdouble-to-double) which consists in looping rather thant trying a savage cast

So my question is : WHY ? what happens behind the scenes in the memory allocation that prevents what may seem - at least at first glance, to be a feasible cast ? I mean structurally, both expression seem to be quite identic. What is it that I am missing here ?

EDIT:
I have to use "double[ ][ ]" as it is provided by an external library.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

One is a jagged array, the other is one big block.

`double[][]` is an array that contains arrays of double. Its form is not necessarily rectangular. In c terms its similar to a `double**`

`double[,]` is just one big block of memory, and it is always rectangular. In c terms it's just a double* where you use `myArray[x+y*width]` to access an element.

Comment: CodeInChaos stroke Again ;-) Always precise and relevant on memory questions. Thanx

Answer (score 6):

One is called [*multidimensional array*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2yd9wwz4%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) (`double[*,*]`) and other is called [*jagged array*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2s05feca%28v=VS.71%29.aspx) (`double[][]`).

Here is a good discussion over differences between them.

[What is differences between Multidimensional array and Array of Arrays in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/597720/what-is-differences-between-multidimensional-array-and-array-of-arrays-in-c)

Answer (score 2):

Quite simply, `[,]` arrays (2D arrays) and `[][]` arrays (jagged arrays) aren't the same.

A `[,]` array can be visually represented by a rectangle (hence it's also known as a rectangular array), while a `[][]` array is a 1D array that contains other 1D arrays.

It wouldn't make much sense to be able to cast one to the other.

Answer (score 1):

You should define your double array like this:

```
double[,] WageLossPerVacationDay  = new double[3, 5];
```

Then it should work!

hth

Comment: Thanx. That was not my point as the code was just an example I have to use an array of arrays actually